# htaccess Redirect with an ampersand

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a simple 301 `Redirect`s that I need to implement on a site that has had some URLs change. All but two work fine, and the two that don't feature an ampersand (actually `%26`) in the URL :

```
Redirect 301 /search/21/0/Hair-%26-Beauty /search/21/0/1/Make-up-and-Hair-%26-Beauty
```

Is there a way I can get the Redirect command to parse the `%26` correctly? I would have tried just using & but these are what the two URLs need to be.

From what I've read I just need to escape the `%26`, but I'm not sure how, or even to find out how.

Thanks for any information.

---

Here's the beginning of my .htaccess file. There are no other rules that could conflict:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ /search.php?S=$1&C=$2&P=$3 [L]
Redirect 301 /search/1/0/Photography http://www.example.com/search/1/0/1/Wedding-Photography
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_rewrite` rules with `%26` used as `\x26`. Use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/21/0/Hair-\x26-Beauty/?$ /search/21/0/1/Make-up-and-Hair-%26-Beauty [L,NE,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately `/search/21/0/Hair-%26-Beauty` is already a Rewritten URL, so this doesn't seem to work I'm afraid.

Comment: Easy, that part of the URL is for SEO, just like here on StackOverflow. Unfortunately I tried it as the very first rule and it still didn't work :-/

Comment: I test it well before posting so rest assured this is a working rule. Only reasons it doesn't work are: You have other conflicting rules OR you have other overlapping htaccess in one of the sub-directory OR your Apache version is not right.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the first rules from the .htaccess. I tried your line as the 2nd line, 5th line and even after the ^search line. Every other similar rule (not having `%26` in it) works fine.

Comment: Thanks for showing .htaccess code, few things look suspect like having `Redrect` directive in mostly `mod_rewrite` based rules. Also you still haven't provided me the full URL you're seeing in browser not getting redirected.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would be obvious from the htaccess I posted: http://www.example.com/search/21/0/Hair-%26-Beauty

Comment: Using this exact rule `localhost/search/21/0/Hair-%26-Beauty` became `localhost/search/21/0/1/Make-up-and-Hair-6-Beauty`. Is `search` a real directory?

Comment: Thanks for your attempts at helping me. You can see from the htaccess that I posted that search is not a directory.

Comment: What is your Apache version? Can you check if there are some rules in Apace server config also?